# Python web data parse

Tags: python

i've been trying to parse data from a website that requires login so i've been using this code below

```
import requests
from lxml import html
session_requests = requests.session()
payload = {
    "login-username": "myusername", 
    "login-password": "mypassword"
}
login_url = "https://oprewards.com/login"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)
url = 'https://oprewards.com/profile'
result = session_requests.get(
    url, 
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)

print(result.content)
```

but it isn't working, I'm not so good at Python so i wish that I can get help there, thanks.

Comment: _but it isn't working_ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this question.

One thing right off the bat is you'll want to check out where actually the login occurs. If you open the network tab, it doesn't send a request to the page that it shows the user, but a different url:

https://oprewards.com/ASEngine/ASAjax.php

I think once you investigate what urls you send your data to you can construct a more accurate request to log yourself in.

[image]

However, if you want to login exactly as a normal user would (that is, by entering in a user/password and clicking the "Login" button, I'd suggest using a browser-automation tool, such as Selenium Webdriver for python: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: I second Selenium, it's the tool for the job + if you are using a non-headless browser you will get direct feedback on what your program is doing @CesarESP

Comment: I'm using a online hosting website so I can't use webdriver, is there another way to use a webdriver? I'm currently on glitch.com, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can install phantomJS webdriver, but it will be headless: https://support.glitch.com/t/chromedriver-and-selenium-webdriver/8171/8 @CesarESP